# How to avoid javascript error on ajax cross domain request

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is it possible to avoid or catch the javascript error without the script to break?

## returns error (empty output)

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    url : '//cvrapi.dk/api?search=dsfsdfsd&country=dk',
    success : function(res){
        if(success){
            success(res);
        }
    }
});
```

## no error is returned (with output)

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    url : '//cvrapi.dk/api?search=test&country=dk',
    success : function(res){
        if(success){
            success(res);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what error? What does `success()` do? Need proper details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one returns a 404 status on the request so you can use `fail()` to catch the bad request and check status:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: '//cvrapi.dk/api?search=dsfsdfsd&country=dk',
  success: function(res) {
    if (success) {
      success(res);
    }
  }
}).fail(function(err) {
  console.log('Something went wrong');
  // check various status as documented by API
  if (err.status === 404) {
    console.log('Not found')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have copy/pasted your code.. `fail` is never executed on `404`.. I use jquery `jquery.1.11.1`

Comment: `jsonp` is a script request and as such has far less error handling capablity than an ajax (XmlHttpRequest) request does. My suggestion is you set up a proxy on your server to make json requests and add all the necessary error handling there

Comment: Its not possible to do that because there is a daily request limit per IP address.. is `fail` not complatible with jquery 1.11.1?

Comment: it is for normal ajax request.... I see it not working though for jsonp